# log4j jars running under the same classloader

Tags: log4j, classloader

I have a problem with log4j, I have several jars, each jar is supposed to write to different log location - but its not happening, the log get written to the same location for all jars together.

I extended the RollingFileAppender class and override the setFile method.

Jars are loaded using the same classloader.

What a i doing wrong?

```
public class CustomRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {
   // some additional methods here...

public synchronized void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    String logFileName = CommonJarClass.getPluginLogRoot() + File.separatorChar + fileName;
    super.setFile(logFileName , append, bufferedIO, bufferSize);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Jars are loaded using the same classloader

Is it a war project ? You are loading all jars ?

> each jar is supposed to write to different log location

Each jar has configured to use your CustomRollingfileAppender ?

Comment: No, Its not a war project, Its a system loading jars as plugins.


Yes, Each jar has configured to use your CustomRollingfileAppender

Comment: If all log4j classes loaded using a same classloader, conflicts will be there. It should be loaded by different JVM to get it working. Or else, try making separate references of log4j.jar for each of your jar project.

Comment: Overriding can not help in your issue. Though you override RollingFileAppender, the CustomRollingFileAppender class should be specified in separate log4j configurations.